# SpelEvaluationException while creating key on @Cacheable in spring cache

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-el, spring-cache

I am trying to cache the data using `@Cacheable` for a method which don’t have parameters/arguments.

Following is my repository code:

```
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Integer>{

   @Cacheable(value = "fooTypes",key = "#root.target.getType().getName()")
   List<Foo> findAll();
}
```

and the Foo entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name”)
public class Foo implements Serializable
{

   private int id;

   private FooType type;

  public FooType getType(){
    return this.type;
  }

}


@Entity
Public class FooType {
    private String name;

    publc String    getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Now when I try to call the findAll() method, following exception is thrown:

*Uncaught runtime error: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 13): Method call: Method getType () cannot be found on com.sun.proxy.$Proxy162 type*

Can someone advice how to configure my cache using FooType field name as key?

Comment: What is `root.target.getType()` ? Where did you define that class ?

Comment: I am assuming root.target evalutes to Foo Object and then I am trying to get the type, based on that I will get the name.

Comment: No. `root.target` evalues to `FooRepository`. Please review the documentation. Your key is really weird as it's expecting a single instance of `Foo` to be available for the key, yet returning a list of them.